# Need workaround for restriction of virtual, abstract static members for .NET implementation of Facebook Flux

Tags: c#, clr, flux, fody

I've looked at a number of Flux implementations in .NET, and think that [this approach](https://alexdunn.org/tag/flux/) is pretty swell:

- It uses static members instead of enums, making XAML nicer
- No need to convert to/from enum types (cleaner code)
- Easy integration with almost any pub/sub mechanism.

That being said, I want to keep the static property-to-string coding technique, but I can't make the following work:

```
public class BitnameTypesBase
{
   // I want to override this in base classes.. but can't 
    public static string ChainName;

    public static string GET_BITNAME = "get_bitname_" + ChainName;
    public static string SEND_BITNAME = "send_bitname_" + ChainName;
    public static string QUERY_BITNAME = "query_bitname_" + ChainName;
}

public class BitcoinBitName :  BitnameTypesBase
{
   // Ouch, can't override field or properties 
    override public static string ChainName = "Bitcoin";

    public static string MySpecialAction = "special_bitname_" + ChainName;
}

public class OthercoinBitName :  BitnameTypesBase
{
   // Ouch, can't override field or properties
    override public static string ChainName = "something new";

    public static string MySpecialAction = "special_bitname_" + ChainName;
}
```

**Question**

- Is there something in the language that will permit this?
- Is there any pre compilation script I can do that will permit this?
- Is there any Fody Plugin that I can use that could help (I didn't see one)

Comment: `public static new string ChainName { get; set; }` will compile, but I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidG I want `BitcoinBitName.STATIC_STRING_IN_CAPS` to be able to be different from one inherited class to another based on the string.join()

Comment: @DavidG made my use case more clear, by adding a second coin, and actually assigning an override value to the property/field. (whichever works)

Comment: OK, so like I said, `new` will work for you here, though it's not really overidding.

Comment: Hey, this is Alex (@Suave_Pirate), the original author of the technique from the post and video. If you want more resources on using Flux with .NET apps, I have a Xamarin University Guest Lecture (not too different from the video in the post, but answers live questions), and a great podcast about it!
Podcast: http://gonemobile.io/blog/e0044.fluxing.up.your.xamarin.apps.with.alex.dunn/
XamU Lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmEtXjfdroY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override a `static` member, but you can hide them by using the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) modifier. For exaple:

```
public class BitnameTypesBase
{
    public static string ChainName;

    public static string GET_BITNAME = "get_bitname_" + ChainName;
    public static string SEND_BITNAME = "send_bitname_" + ChainName;
    public static string QUERY_BITNAME = "query_bitname_" + ChainName;
}

public class BitcoinBitName :  BitnameTypesBase
{
    public static new string ChainName = "Bitcoin";
    public static string MySpecialAction = "special_bitname_" + ChainName;
}

public class OthercoinBitName : BitnameTypesBase
{
    public static new string ChainName = "something new";
    public static string MySpecialAction = "special_bitname_" + ChainName;
}
```

And now:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitcoinBitName.MySpecialAction);
Console.WriteLine(OthercoinBitName.MySpecialAction);
```

Will output:

```
special_bitname_Bitcoin
special_bitname_something new
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a classical OO option (I use this pattern a lot):

```
public abstract class BitnameTypesBase
{
    public abstract string ChainName { get; }

    public string GET_BITNAME => "get_bit_name" + ChainName;
    public string SEND_BITNAME => "send_bitname_" + ChainName;
    public string QUERY_BITNAME => "query_bitname_" + ChainName;

    public virtual string MySpecialAction => "special_bitname_" + ChainName;

    public abstract class Of<T> : BitnameTypesBase where T : BitnameTypesBase, new()
    {
        public readonly static T Instance = new T();
    }
}

public sealed class BitcoinBitName : BitnameTypesBase.Of<BitcoinBitName>
{
    public override string ChainName= > "bitcoin";
}

public sealed class OthercoinName : BitnameTypesBase.Of<OthercoinName>
{
    public override string ChainName => "something new";
}

//other coins defined similarly
```

Then, you use like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitnameTypesBase.Of<BitcoinBitName>.Instance.MySpecialAction);
Console.WriteLine(BitnameTypesBase.Of<OthercoinName>.Instance.MySpecialAction);
```

If the verbosity is a bit much, you could always declare static members on the base class that reference those instances:

```
public abstract class  BitnameTypesBase
{
    BitnameTypeBase Bitcoin = Of<BitcoinBitName>.Instance;
    BitnameTypeBase Othercoin = Of<OthercoinName>.Instance;

    //the rest of the class as defined before

}
```

Then the use sites become:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitnameTypesBase.Bitcoin.MySpecialAction);
Console.WriteLine(BitnameTypesBase.Othercoin.MySpecialAction);
```

Even better: if you're using C# 6 or greater then you can add a `using static BitnameTypesBase;` to the top of your file (among the other `using namespace ...` declarations), so the use sites become:

```
Console.WriteLine(Bitcoin.MySpecialAction);
Console.WriteLine(Othercoin.MySpecialAction);
```